# Getting Bad Request with a large url

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I'm receveing a Bad Request when i call a large url.

```
https://localhost:44320/RespostaEmail/96635/750396/[%7B%22IdItem%22:8,%22IdTipoReposta%22:80%7D,%7B%22IdItem%22:1,%22IdTipoReposta%22:80%7D,%7B%22IdItem%22:3,%22IdTipoReposta%22:80%7D,%7B%22IdItem%22:2,%22IdTipoReposta%22:80%7D,%7B%22IdItem%22:5,%22IdTipoReposta%22:80%7D,%7B%22IdItem%22:7,%22IdTipoReposta%22:80%7D,%7B%22IdItem%22:10,%22IdTipoReposta%22:80%7D,%7B%22IdItem%22:4,%22IdTipoReposta%22:80%7D,%7B%22IdItem%22:6,%22IdTipoReposta%22:80%7D,%7B%22IdItem%22:9,%22IdTipoReposta%22:80%7D]
```

I redirect to this url when i call this function in javascript

```
function responder(idDivergencia, numGF, dia, mes, ano) {
let observacao = $('#observacao').val();

if (observacao.trim() == '') {
    abrirDialogAlertaMensagem('Informe uma observação para visualizar a tela de resposta.');
    return;
}

while (observacao.indexOf('/') != -1) {
    observacao = observacao.replace('/', '-')
}

var lista = ObterListaDeItens(idDivergencia, numGF);
var itens;

if (lista != null) {

    $('.btnSalvarDiv').click();
    itens = JSON.stringify(lista);

    window.location.href = RELATIVE_PATH + 'RespostaEmail/' + idDivergencia + '/' + numGF + '/' + itens
} else {
    abrirDialogAlertaMensagem('Informe o(s) tipo(s) de resposta para visualizar a tela de resposta.');
    return;
}
```

}

and that's my controller

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("RespostaEmail/{idDivergencia}/{numeroGf}/{itensDivergencia}")]
    public IActionResult RespostaEmail(int idDivergencia, int numeroGf, string itensDivergencia)
    {
        if (itensDivergencia == "favicon.ico")
            return View();

        var listaItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItemResposta>>(itensDivergencia);

        var breadcrumb = BreadcrumbControl.GetInstance();
        breadcrumb.AddNewPage("Resposta Email", "Resposta", "RespostaEmail");

        var dados = new Resposta();
        var itens = _divergenciaAppService.ListarItensDivergencia(idDivergencia);

        foreach (var item in itens)
        {
            dados.ItemSolicitado.Add(new ItemSolicitado
            {
                CodigoDivergencia = item.CodDivergencia,
                IdGrupo = item.IdGrupo,
                IdItem = item.IdItem,
                Peca = item.PecaSolicitada,
                Quantidade = item.QtdDivergente ?? 0,
                TipoResposta = listaItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdItem == item.IdItem).IdTipoReposta
            });
        }

        dados.IdDivergencia = idDivergencia;
        dados.NumeroGF = numeroGf;

        var email = _respostaAppService.MontarEmailResposta(dados);

        ViewBag.TextoPadrao = email;
        ViewBag.IdDivergencia = idDivergencia;
        ViewBag.Conta = ContaUsuario;
        ViewBag.IdGrupo = dados.ItemSolicitado.Select(x => x.IdGrupo).LastOrDefault();
        return View();
    }
```

I am trying to configure the max length but i'm not finding where to config this, my project is in .netcore 3.1. That has a Startup, but i cannot find where i can solve this problem. Or someone has other ways to deal with this problem.

Comment: There is a limit for url length. But for the query string, which is way much larger you can change it to a query string.

Comment: That string really isn't all that long: you should be able to get to about 2000 characters before running into issues. How sure are you that this is a length problem? Does it work correctly if you have fewer items? The server may be choking on the bracket characters: your javascript is not encoding the list--use encodeURIComponent() to encode that URI segment.

Comment: Hi Willian, do you have any concern about this issue ? If you have fixed the issue, could you share with us, it may help more forum users^-^

Comment: You have brackets in your URL. Did you properly escape them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using query string. The url still be large but with query string this issue didn't happen.

I changed my javascript to

```
function responder(idDivergencia, numGF, dia, mes, ano) {
...

var queryString = '?idDivergencia=' + idDivergencia + '&numeroGf=' + numGF + '&itensDivergencia=' + itensCodificado;

window.location.href = RELATIVE_PATH + 'RespostaEmail/' + queryString

...
}
```

and my controller to

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("RespostaEmail")]
public IActionResult RespostaEmail(int idDivergencia, int numeroGf, string itensDivergencia)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your problem in my computer.
I actually cannot reproduce it in local environment, I got a 200 response in localhost. The problem occurs on the IIS server.
I tried in different browers and nothing changed. I tried a shorter url, it did work, which means it is the problem of large url, So it is caused by the server limit.
We can change the webserver configuration in the web.config,

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
    <security>
          <requestFiltering>
              <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="30000000" maxUrl="30000000" maxQueryString="30000000" />
          </requestFiltering>
        </security>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication1.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
          <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="999999999" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" maxUrlLength="2097151" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

which is automatically generated in the root directory of my publish-file when using IIS 10, to enlarger the url length limit. However it didn’t work, and is also not recommended. Large url can cause a long responding time and some other problems.

[responsing time of long url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43KWb.png)
[image: responsing time of long url]

[responsing time of short url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eccJU.png)
[image: responsing time of short url]

We can simply change the GET method to a POST one, to contain part of the request in the body is safer and more efficient.
Just write the javascript in the js file and change the Action to a httpPost one.

.js

```
function responder(idDivergencia, numGF, dia, mes, ano) {
...
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.open('POST');
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

if (lista != null) {
    …

    window.location.href = RELATIVE_PATH + 'RespostaEmail/';
    var body = idDivergencia + '/' + numGF + '/' + itens
    httpRequest.send(body);
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    …
    }
} else {
    ...
}
```

}

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("RespostaEmail")]
public IActionResult RespostaEmail(int idDivergencia, int numeroGf, string 
itensDivergencia)
{
…
}
```

[the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjF95.png)

[image: the response]